# Detect non blocking threads in micronaut netty

Tags: netty, project-reactor, micronaut

In my Micronauts app, in my blocking code, I would like to detect if I'm not accidentally working on a non-blocking Event Loop thread.

I was thinking about using reactor.core.scheduler.Schedulers#isInNonBlockingThread but Netty threads don't implement the expected interface.

Is there any way to achieve that in Micronauts with Netty?

Answer (score 0):

`BlockHound` is what you are looking for: https://github.com/reactor/BlockHound

it is a java-agent that checks for blocking code in identified non-blocking threads.

Netty integrates with its SPI (see this [PR](https://github.com/netty/netty/pull/9687)), so all you need to do is install it in your tests (or use the junit-platform support).